# form the equivalent matrix equation and augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

what does it mean when it tells you `form the equivalent matrix equation and augmented matrix`

lets say I have something like this

```
3x - 8y + 10z = 22 
   x - 3y + 2z = 5
```

would I just write that like this ? would this be correct ?

```
3 -8  10 | 22       
1 -3   2 | 5
```

I dont know what equivalent matrix equation means...

Comment: I don't know what "equivalent matrix" is either within this context (it perhaps is a local thing, as I'm almost sure it isn't international), but that you wrote is the augmented matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the set of equations, $$\begin{align} 3x_1 - 8x_2 + 10x_3 &= 22 \\ x_1 - 3x_2 + 2x_3 &= 5\end{align}$$ The *coefficient matrix* is,
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}3&-8&10\\1&-1&2\end{bmatrix}$$ and if we let $$ b = \begin{bmatrix} 22\\5 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the matrix equation that is equivalent to the original system of linear equations is: $Ax = b$. This is the *equivalent matrix form* of the original system of linear equations.

and, finally,  the augmented matrix is exactly what you already know it is...namely, 
$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}3&-8&10&22\\1&-1&2&5\end{array} \right]$$

Comment: thank you...you're awesome!...now I get what equivalent matrix is

Comment: Oh, i have to edit my answer...I just noticed your question asked for the equvalent matrix equation...not just the equivalent matrix! Sorry! Edits coming...

Comment: wait...your answer is not enough ?

Comment: ok....now it is better. sorry again. (and thank you  a bunch for accepting and the upvote!)